# Can't find the logical bug

Tags: c

I have solved this [programming problem](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=downloadproblem&probid=110201&format=html) and when I submitted my code, the judge said it was wrong. I tried and I couldn't figure out the bug. Can someone give me a hint please?

Because stack overflow won't accept my question if I don't specify more details, I am copying the question here

A sequence of n > 0 integers is called a jolly jumper if the absolute values of the
differences between successive elements take on all possible values 1 through n − 1. For
instance,
1 4 2 3
is a jolly jumper, because the absolute differences are 3, 2, and 1, respectively. The
definition implies that any sequence of a single integer is a jolly jumper. Write a program
to determine whether each of a number of sequences is a jolly jumper.

Input
Each line of input contains an integer n < 3, 000 followed by n integers representing the
sequence.

Output
For each line of input generate a line of output saying “Jolly” or “Not jolly”.

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SEQ_SIZE 3000

static char stack[SEQ_SIZE];

void initStack(int count)
{
    for(int i=0;i<count; ++i)
        stack[i]=0;
}

int absDiff(int a, int b)
{
    return (a-b)>=0?((a-b)%SEQ_SIZE):(((a-b)*-1)%SEQ_SIZE);
}

int main()
{
    int n,prev,curr;
    /*FILE *sample=fopen("SampleInput","r");
    if(!sample)
        return 0;*/
    while(scanf("%d",&n)!=EOF)
    {
        scanf("%d",&prev);
        if(n<1)
            break;
        else if(n==1)
            printf("Jolly\n");
        else
        {
            int i;
            for(i=1; i<n; ++i)
            {
                scanf("%d",&curr);
                stack[absDiff(curr,prev)-1]=1;
                prev=curr;
            }
            for(i=0; i<(n-1); ++i)
            {
                if(stack[i]==0)
                    break;
            }
            if(i<n-1)
                printf("Not jolly\n");
            else
                printf("Jolly\n");
            initStack(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try initializing the stack in the beginning also.

Comment: I did try initializing the stack at the beginning, but the solution is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is fine except the line

```
return (a-b)>=0?((a-b)%SEQ_SIZE):(((a-b)*-1)%SEQ_SIZE);
```

No need to use `%` here. It should be

```
return (a-b)>=0?((a-b)): (a-b)*(-1));
```

To limit `n` below `3000` you can do as

```
if(n<1 || n >= 3000) // I merged it with n<1 condition
    break;
```

Comment: The only reason I added the mod SEQ_SIZE was because I wasn't sure where the logical bug was and I wanted to eliminate the possibility of the index going beyond limit. Even with your suggested changes the solution is not being accepted.